# Assignments in a map end up as 0?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am a beginner to C++, and recently I was working on a USACO training program about gift-giving. However, while the output is supposed to show the names of everyone involved and their respective cash amounts, mine always ends up as all zeros. Here is my code:

```
/*
ID: afuhrtr1
PROG: gift1
LANG: C++
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    stringstream ss;
    ofstream fout ("gift1.out");
    ifstream fin ("gift1.in");
    int np;
    fin >> np;
    string people [np];
    map<string, int> amounts;
    for (int i = 0; i < np; i++)
    {
        string name;
        fin >> name;
        //amounts[name]=0;
        people[i] = name;
    }
    while (fin.good())
    {
        string giver;
        fin >> giver;
        string twoNumbers;
        fin >> twoNumbers;
        int spacePos = twoNumbers.find(' ');
        int amount;
        ss << twoNumbers.substr(0, spacePos);
        ss >> amount;
        int npgiven;
        ss << twoNumbers.substr(spacePos+1);
        ss >> npgiven;
        for (int i = 0; i < npgiven; i++)
        {
            string name;
            fin >> name;
            amounts[name]+=(amount/npgiven);
        }
        amounts[giver]+=(amount % npgiven - amount);
    }
    map<string, int>::iterator it;
    for (int i = 0; i < np; i++)
        fout << people[i] << " " << amounts[people[i]] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm assuming the problem is either assigning stuff to the map elements, or the fin.good() call.

Also, here's the contest scenario:

A group of NP (2 ≤ NP ≤ 10) uniquely named friends has decided to exchange gifts of money. Each of these friends might or might not give some money to any or all of the other friends. Likewise, each friend might or might not receive money from any or all of the other friends. Your goal in this problem is to deduce how much more money each person gives than they receive.

The rules for gift-giving are potentially different than you might expect. Each person sets aside a certain amount of money to give and divides this money evenly among all those to whom he or she is giving a gift. No fractional money is available, so dividing 3 among 2 friends would be 1 each for the friends with 1 left over -- that 1 left over stays in the giver's "account".

In any group of friends, some people are more giving than others (or at least may have more acquaintances) and some people have more money than others.

Given a group of friends, no one of whom has a name longer than 14 characters, the money each person in the group spends on gifts, and a (sub)list of friends to whom each person gives gifts, determine how much more (or less) each person in the group gives than they receive.

INPUT FORMAT
Line 1:     The single integer, NP
Lines 2..NP+1:  Each line contains the name of a group member
Lines NP+2..end:    NP groups of lines organized like this:
The first line in the group tells the person's name who will be giving gifts.
The second line in the group contains two numbers: The initial amount of money (in the range 0..2000) to be divided up into gifts by the giver and then the number of people to whom the giver will give gifts, NGi (0 ≤ NGi ≤ NP-1).
If NGi is nonzero, each of the next NGi lines lists the the name of a recipient of a gift.

Comment: Integer divided by integer is likely not what you want.

Comment: You don't check for errors, so how can you be sure they were read successfully? Also, VLAs are not C++.

Comment: Amount will always be much larger than npgiven and the division is meant to be uneven, so I do want int/int I think. USACO does not have any kind of debugger, so I'm not sure I can check for logic errors effectively but there are no compiler error. Also, where is this VLA?

Comment: `string people [np];` declares a Variable Length Array (VLA).

Comment: The first step is to instrument up your code with "`printf`" debugging: well, print to the screen what you read, where you put it, and how you change it.  See what surprises you in that narrative.

Answer (score 0):

> USACO does not have any kind of debugger, so I'm not sure I can check for logic errors effectively but there are no compiler error.

That's your main problem.

Surely you can run this code in an environment with a debugger available? There are freely-available C++ development environments.  You can't code C++ without a debugger.  StackOverflow is not an efficient debugger ;)

Comment: Well I have Code::Blocks installed, but I for some reason I can't get the compiler path to be set correctly so I can't run anything.

Comment: If you can't debug it, printf & cout are your friends then;)